# Your Facebook SDK is out of date issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have setup facebook sdk in my app in Unity and in meta developer's page. But i have following issue: [image]

I also setup release key hashes.My facebook sdk version is latest 16.0. Why this message shown?